# What were the dates of Bitcoin's previous price plummets prior to 2015? What articles were written about it?

Tags: price-volatility

As of Jan 2015, the price of Bitcoin has plummeted from 300ish to 200 since the summer of 2014. This wasn't the first time happening to have the price plummet in such a state where mass media starts reporting "**the death of bitcoin**".

- What were the previous dates and percentage drops in USD that caught mass media attention prior to 2015 Jan?
- What were some of the articles that were reported on these dates believing that Bitcoin is about to die? And by whom?

Comment: You might find [**bitcoinobituaries.com**](http://bitcoinobituaries.com/) helpful, which collects articles that report Bitcoin's imminent death.

Answer (score 4):

The most notable cases were:

- In 2011, the price reached a peak of $32 in June, and went down all the way to $2 in November. A decrease by a x16 factor, or 93.75%.
- In 2013, the price reached a peak of $266 in April, and quickly afterwards went down to the $65 range. A 75% drop.

This can be seen graphically [here](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#tgSzm1g10zm2g25zvzl) and [here](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/bitstampUSD#tgSzm1g10zm2g25zvzl).

As for media coverage, [this list of "obituaries"](http://bitcoinobituaries.com/) is handy. Among the most infamous (at least, around people who were around that long) is wired.com's 2011 piece "[The Rise and Fall of Bitcoin](http://www.wired.com/2011/11/mf_bitcoin/all/)".